# Redis unit test using redis mock

Tags: unit-testing, redis

I'm using the [following](https://dzone.com/articles/java-redis-mock) tool to run an embedded redis for unit testing.

In the beginning of my **registrationService** is creating a new instance of redis server.

```
@Import({RedisConfiguration.class})
@Service
public class RegistrationService

RedisTemplate redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate();  //<- new instance

public String SubmitApplicationOverview(String OverviewRequest) throws IOException {

    . . .

    HashMap<String,Object> applicationData = mapper.readValue(OverviewRequest,new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});

    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());

    UUID Key = UUID.randomUUID();

    redisTemplate.opsForHash().putAll(Key.toString(), (applicationData)); //<-- ERRORS HERE

    System.out.println("Application saved:" + OverviewRequest);

    return Key.toString();
 }
}
```

And I'm starting a mock redis server in my **Test** below.

```
...

RedisServer redisServer;

@Autowired
RegistrationService RegistrationService;

@Before
public void Setup() {
    redisServer = RedisServer.newRedisServer();
    redisServer.start();
}

@Test
public void testSubmitApplicationOverview() {
    String body = "{\n" +
            "    \"VehicleCategory\": \"CAR\",\n" +
            "    \"EmailAddress\": \"email@email.com\"\n" +
            "}";
    String result = RegistrationService.SubmitApplicationOverview(body);

    Assert.assertEquals("something", result);
}
```

Redis settings in **application.properties**

```
#Redis Settings
spring.redis.cluster.nodes=slave0:6379,slave1:6379
spring.redis.url= redis://jx-staging-redis-ha-master-svc.jx-staging:6379
spring.redis.sentinel.master=mymaster
spring.redis.sentinel.nodes=10.40.2.126:26379,10.40.1.65:26379
spring.redis.database=2
```

However, I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` **error on the following line** in my service under test (registrationService).

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().putAll(Key.toString(), (applicationData));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `[redis-mock][1]` documentation, creating an instance like this:

```
RedisServer.newRedisServer();  // bind to a random port
```

Will bind the instance to a random port. It looks like your code expects a specific port. I believe that you need to specify a port when you create the server by passing a port number like this:

```
RedisServer.newRedisServer(8000);  // bind to a specific port
```